# Mysql Many to Many relation Navicat Fail Constraint

Tags: mysql, many-to-many, relational-database, foreign-key-relationship, navicat

Im bulding a new Data Model Diagram for my project and im having troubles creating a Many to Many relation.

I´ve posted a screenshot of the diagram specificly on the part that need work.

Im getting this error:

**The cardinality is not possible to be realized with current constraint(s)**

Here is the screenshot:
http://clip2net.com/s/1K1EH (Please, let me know if the image is no longer avaliable)

In the image you´ll notice 3 tables:
produtoloja,
produtopedido,
pedido,

**produtoloja** -> Hold information of products

**produtopedido** -> Makes the relation between produtoloja and pedido

**pedido** -> Holds information about the order of the product

Tables information:

Table **produtoloja**:

Primary Keys:

```
   - ProdutolojaId
```

Indexes:

```
   - (ProdutoId, LojaId) ->NON-UNIQUE
   - ProdutoLojaId -> UNIQUE
```

Table **produtopedido**

Primary Keys:

```
  - (ProdutoLojaId,PedidoId)
```

Indexes:

```
  - ProdutoLojaId -> NON-UNIQUE
```

Foreign Keys:

```
  [Name]fk_produtopedido_pedido_1:
     - [Fields] PedidoId
     - [Reference Table] pedido
     - [Reference Fields] PedidoId

  [Name]fk_produtopedido_produtoloja_1:
     - [Fields] ProdutoLojaId
     - [Reference Table] produtoloja
     - [Reference Fields] ProdutoLojaId
```

Table **pedido**

Primary Keys:

```
  - PedidoId
```

Indexes:

```
  - PedidoId -> UNIQUE
  - LojaId -> NON-UNIQUE
```

As you can see in the screenshot, Navicat is accusing an invalid relation between these tables. So my question is, what am i doing wrong? Are my primary keys and indexes ok? What can i do to improve this?

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: the image is no longer available

Answer (score 1):

Can't see the image, but here's a guess: PK in produtoloja has a lower-case "L", while the referencing FK in produtopedido has it in upper-case.

[image]